# Wordpress - deactivate single page for posts

Tags: wordpress, post

is it possible to deactivate the single page for posts? I found solutions, but they are redirecting to a 404 page. I would prefer a solution to completly deactivate it, in a way, wordpress doens't even produce this pages.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Mind sharing with us why you need to do this?

Comment: I don't need the single page, because my posts will be very small, just some lines of text. I want the blog page, but not the single ones. My idea was to leave out the links to this pages (it is a custom theme), but I am afraid that google registers this pages.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In that case, why not just do a 301 redirect from your single posts to your blog page instead? That way a) search engines won't index your single post pages due to the redirect, and b) visitors won't see these pages either.

Comment: oh thank you, I didn't have this idea. I am not sure how to use redirects, but this I will find out.
Thank you very much .)